# C# - secure `sockets` with SSL

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl

hi i have a socket connection (server) developed with methods available in

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
```

is it possible to secure the data communication in this sockets ? specially implement **SSL** ? any examples ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an [SslStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream). The documentation link contains an example of a TCP server and a client which communicate over SSL.

Comment: @Sudantha, no, it works with bare sockets as well, but you probably shouldn't be using bare sockets anyway. SslStream can be used to wrap any Stream object, no matter where it comes from.

Comment: do u have any example with `sslstream` ? my client is on `PHP` is it possible ?

Comment: @Sudantha, isn't the link provided in the documentation insufficient for you to implement the server side? As far as the client side is concerned, I am not familiar with PHP, but I guess that if it supports SSL over TCP sockets that would work (as I don't know PHP I cannot point you towards good examples of how to achieve this). You will need a certificate on the server.